# PHP Checkbox Form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm trying to post the output of a checkbox to email however I'm having real difficulty?
Anyone any idea:

```
$inputName = $_POST["inputName"];
$inputDate = $_POST["inputDate"];
$inputStart = $_POST["inputStart"];
$inputEnd = $_POST["inputEnd"];
$inputFacilities = $_POST["inputFacilities"];
//$inputAssistanceDuration = $_POST["inputAssistanceDuration"];
$inputComment = $_POST["inputComment"];

if (isset($_POST['inputAssistanceSetup'])) {
    // Checkbox is selected
    $inputAssistanceSetup = ["Yes"];
} else {
    // Alternate code
    $inputAssistanceSetup = ["No"];
}


if ( empty($_POST['inputAssistanceDuration']) ) {
    // Checkbox is selected
    $inputAssistanceDuration = ["No"];
} else {
    // Alternate code
    $inputAssistanceDuration = ["Yes"];
}




require_once "Mail.php";
$from = '"IT Request" <example@gmail.com>';
$to = '<example@gmail.com>,<example@gmail.com>';
$subject = "IT Facilities Request: {$inputName}";
$body = "Name: {$inputName}\nDate: {$inputDate}\nFrom: {$inputStart}\nUntil: {$inputEnd}\nFacilities: {$inputFacilities}\nAssistance for Setup: {$inputAssistanceSetup}\nAssistance for Duration: {$inputAssistanceDuration}\nComment: {$inputComment}";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
```

My HTML form is:

```
                    <!--IT Support Assistance-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputAssistance" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Assistance</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="inputAssistanceSetup" value="Setup" type="checkbox"> For Setup
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="inputAssistanceDuration" value="Duration" type="checkbox"> For Duration
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I really have no idea as to why this isn't working, as I'm simply using an IF statement to determine it?
Please help!

Comment: You should check its existence using `isset($_POST['inputAssistanceSetup'])`

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `$inputAssistanceSetup = ["Yes"];` assigned value in brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to.

```
if (isset($_POST['inputAssistanceSetup'])) {
    // Checkbox is selected
    $inputAssistanceSetup = "Yes";
} else {
    // Alternate code
    $inputAssistanceSetup = "No";
}

if ( isset($_POST['inputAssistanceDuration']) ) {
    // Checkbox is selected
    $inputAssistanceDuration = "Yes";
} else {
    // Alternate code
    $inputAssistanceDuration = "No";
}
```

Comment: Hm, this seems to be getting there. The email output now displays 'NO' regardless of the box being checked now?

Comment: @GlenRitchie what do you mean by email output now displays 'NO'

Comment: The output shows the following: Facilities: test (break) Assistance for Setup: No (break) Assistance for Duration: No (break) Comment: none
Even if the box is checked...

Comment: Try this `echo $_POST["inputComment"];` and see if you get comment.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad choice of input the 'comment' text field works fine, the check boxes return the output 'No' regardless of their status.

Comment: You should get checkbox value using `$inputAssistanceSetup` and `$inputAssistanceDuration`

Comment: If you tick the checkbox it will return Yes else it will return No

Comment: That's what you'd expect, but unfortunately that didn't work the first time? Strange...! Thanks!